# VS2013, regex. Why do I get 'string iterators incompatible'?

Tags: regex, exception, visual-studio-2013, iterator

I am compiling the following code with VS2013:

```
   if (std::regex_match(string("10-11-1982 11:22:31"), match, std::regex("(\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{4} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2})"))) {
            std::cout << "Match size:" << match.size() << std::endl;
            for (size_t i = 0; i < match.size(); ++i) {
                std::ssub_match sub_match = match[i];
                std::string piece = sub_match.str(); // <-- Interrumption here
                std::cout << "  submatch " << i << ": " << piece << '\n';
            }
        }
```

When the commented line is executed the following dialog appears:

[image]

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `string` like that, although the compiler says it's OK.

Just declare your input string as `string` and then pass the variable to the `regex_match` method.

This works:

```
string line1 = "10-11-1982 11:22:31";

if (std::regex_match(line1, match, std::regex("(\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{4} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2})"))) {
        std::cout << "Match size:" << match.size() << std::endl;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < match.size(); ++i) {
            std::ssub_match sub_match = match[i];
            std::string piece = sub_match.str(); // <-- Interrumption here
            std::cout << "  submatch " << i << ": " << piece << '\n';
        }
    }
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. btw why are there 2 matches?

Comment: There are 2 groups a regex match returns: 0th group that is equal to the whole matched substring, and the 1st that is the substring captured by the parenthetical part of your pattern (you set it to the whole match). I think in this case, the capturing group is redundant, remove the round brackets.

Answer (score 2):

When you call:

```
std::regex_match(string("10-11-1982 11:22:31"), match, std::regex("..."))
```

This creates a temporary `std::string` containing the value `"10-11-1982 11:22:31"`, and this temporary string is deleted when the `std::regex_match()` call returns.

The `match` object internally keeps iterators to the string on which it has been created. When you call `sub_match.str()`, a check is performed to see if these iterators still point to a valid `std::string`. Since, at this point, this string is destroyed, the check fails.